# Find $k$ max such as $I_n-A_1A_2...A_k$ is invertible, then so is $I_n-A_{\pi(1)}A_{\pi(2)}...A_{\pi(k)}$ for every permutation.

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

> Let $ n \ge 2$ be an integer. Find the largest integer $ k \ge 1$ 
>   with the following property: for any $k$ matrices: $A_1,A_2,...,A_k
> \in \mathcal{M}_n(\mathbb{C})$, if $I_n-A_1A_2...A_k$ is invertible,
>   then so is $I_n-A_{\pi(1)}A_{\pi(2)}...A_{\pi(k)}$ for every
>   permutation $\pi \in S_k$.

RNMO SHL 2004

Comment: Of course, $k\geq 2$

Answer (score 2):

First of all note that if $I-AB$ is invertible then $I-BA$ is also invertible, this implies that If $I-A_1A_2\cdots,A_m$ is ivertible then any circular permutation of the product $I-A_iA_{i+1}\cdots A_mA_1\cdots A_{i-1}$ is invertible.

For example if $I-ABC$ is invertible then $I-BCA,I-CAB$ are also invertible, but this does not cover all matrices in fact we can find three matrices such that $I-ABC$ is invertible and $I-ACB$ is not invertible:

Take $$A=\begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0   \end{pmatrix},B =\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0  \\ \textrm{i} & 0  \end{pmatrix},C =\begin{pmatrix}  0 & \textrm{i} \\  0 & 0   \end{pmatrix}.$$ Then $$BC = \begin{pmatrix}   0 & 0 \\  0 & -1 \end{pmatrix},$$ thus $$I_2 - ABC = I_2,$$ while $$CB = \begin{pmatrix} -1 & 0  \\ 0 & 0  \end{pmatrix},$$ thus $$I_3 - ACB = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ This can be extended over $\mathbb{C}$ to any $n\geq 2$.

As an answer to the problem $k=2$

Here is [Source of the counter example.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c7t291f7h1071790_i_dont_find_an_example_of_this)

Comment: Same example works for $2\times 2$: just delete the middle row and column.